# Assign values in a one to one relation

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have created an entity "computer" and an entity "user" in Rapidclipse (using Vaadin and JPA/Hibernate).
These two entites are connected via a one to one relation.

**Entity Computer**

```java
@Entity
@DAO(daoClass = ComputerDAO.class)
@Cacheable(true)
@Table(name = "computer")
public class Computer implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    ...
    private User user;
    ...
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(final int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    ...
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }
    public void setUser(final User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    ...
}
```

**Entity User**

```java
@Entity
@DAO(daoClass = UserDAO.class)
@Cacheable(true)
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    ...
    private Computer computer;
    ...
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(final int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    ...
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "sps") 
    public Computer getComputer() {
        return this.computer;
    }
    public void setComputer(final Computer computer) {
        this.computer = computer;
    }
    ...
}
```

I have already created a few computers in my database. Via a field group, I am trying to assign a certain user to a certain computer. Therefore I have text fields to input the user data to create a new user and a list select to choose the linked computer. With a save button I want to create this new user with the selected connection to the computer.

```java
...
this.fieldGroup.setItemDataSource(new User());
...
private void cmdSave_buttonClick(final Button.ClickEvent event){
    this.fieldGroup.save(); // the user gets created, but there is no link to the computer
    this.listSelect.getSelectedItem().getBean().setUser(this.fieldGroup.getItemDataSource().getBean()); // i am trying to link them manually, but it does not work
}
```

As described the problem is, that the link between computer and user is not written into the database. In the table computer the attribute user_id is always null. So why doesn't it work to set the user manually?

Comment: have you enabled **auto increment** of user table in mysql?

Comment: @varman i have added the database setting to the post.

Comment: In `Computer#setUser()` add code `if (user.getComputer() != this) { user.setComputer(this)}` and preferably also add that the other way around to `User#setComputer()` you might have to remove `final` for that, alternatively just add `this.listSelect.getSelectedItem().getBean().getUser().setComputer(this.listSelect.getSelectedItem().getBean())` to `cmdSave_buttonClick` but if you want to do that there then I advice to create a local variable for the computer

Comment: @nidaav I haven't seen any **auto increment** added in the tables. If you add Auto increment, it will show **"AUTO_INCREMENT"** in *Extra*

Comment: @varman the id gets automatically assigned - first computer (id=1), first user (id=2), second computer (id=3), second user (id=4),...

Comment: @nidaav sure, but the will be automatically increased when you define it as a auto increment only. Otherwise it defines null.

Comment: Try to put auto increment whether its working or not

Comment: @varman so where do i have to enable auto increment? I only can do auto increment for the id of the computer

Comment: @nidaav in mysql add auto increment to primary key

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't save my problem. @varman

Comment: Any errors? Now auto increment works?

Comment: The id of the computer increases by 1 every time i create a new entry. But it was the same beofre i enabled auto increment

Comment: I don't get why this does not work: `this.listSelect.getSelectedItem().getBean().setUser(this.fieldGroup.getItemDataSource().getBean());`

Answer (score 0):

- User user = new User(...);
- Computer computer = new Computer(...);
- user.setComputer(computer);
- computer.setUser(user);
- userDao.save(user);

This will save both User and Computer Objects.

Comment: I did this `private void cmdSave_buttonClick(final Button.ClickEvent event){
    this.fieldGroup.save(); User user = new User(); Computer computer = new Computer(); user.setComputer(computer); computer.setUser(user); UserDAO userDao = new UserDAO(); userDao.save(user);}` But in table computer of the database the user_id still remains null. And an error occured: Error during managed flush

Answer (score 0):

Try editing you `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` annotation that it looks like the following:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

The CascadeType specifies what operations are propagated to the related entities. it will make sure that the entity where it relates to, will be stored in the database as well.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not fix my problem. The user id for the selected computer remain null...